# Как решить проблему Invalid Syntax SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я новичок в Python, и я захотел сделать калькулятор.
Мне вылезла ошибка:

```
    print("Сумма — " + str(answer))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Вот его код:

```py
first_number = int(input("Введите число "))
second_number = int(input("Введите второе число "))
act = input("Введите символ действия (+ — сложить, - — вычесть, * — умножить, / — разделить ")
if act == "+":
    try:
     answer = first_number + second_number
    print("Сумма — " + str(answer))
if act == "-":
    try:
     answer = first_number - second_number
    print("Разность — " + str(answer))

    if act == "*":
    try:
     answer = first_number * second_number
    print("Произведение — " + str(answer))
if act == "/":
    try:
     answer = first_number / second_number
    except ZeroDivisionError:
     answer = "Делить на нуль нельзя!"
    print(answer)
```

[image]

Comment: соблюдайте пробелы и табы.....

Comment: Также, не бывает try без except

Comment: Да, тут из-за отсутствия `except:` явно ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try - это функция, которая связана с except, ты не можешь просто написать try ... и не написать except, поэтому и возникает ошибка в синтаксисе. Если тебе в случае ошибки ничего не надо делать можешь написать:
try:
#code
except:
pass
#pass - это функция, которая ничего не делать(просто заполняет место)

можно без pass, главное, чтобы там что-то выполнялось

Comment: Да и try тебе кроме как ошибки деления на ноль там не нужен, можешь его убрать и ничего не поменяется

Comment: Спасибо!! Помогло! Теперь запускается!